# Problem with infinitesimals and approximations

Tags: calculus

I'm reading about infitesimals and I came accros the following calculation.

Suppose f is differentiable at point a.

$Δf - dy = Δf - f'(a)Δx = (\frac{Δy}{Δx} - f'(a))\cdot Δx = ε\cdot Δx$

So, as Δx$\rightarrow 0$ it is that $\frac{Δy}{Δx}\rightarrow f'(a)$ and therefore ε$\rightarrow 0$(based on the textbook)

But the definition of $\frac{Δy}{Δx}$ as Δx approaches 0 is exactly f'(a) so why ε$\rightarrow 0$ and not ε=$0$.

The textbook im using is Thoma's calculus 14 edition. This can be found in chapter 3.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because although $\Delta x \to 0$ causes $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \to f'(a)$, note it's a limiting case, where the fraction normally never actually reaches the integral value, although it will become arbitrarily close as $\Delta x$ becomes small enough. In particular, you have by definition of derivatives that

$$\lim_{\Delta x \to 0}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = f'(a) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Note with limits that you have the variable approach the limiting value, but never actually get there since, in some cases, the expression being checked doesn't even have a value there (e.g., with $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$, you get $\frac{0}{0}$). Thus, you can't have $\Delta x$ actually be $0$, although it can become arbitrarily close. As such, in general, you have, from what you wrote

$$\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} - f'(a) = \epsilon \neq 0 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

As you noted in your comment below, $\epsilon$ is not a constant but, rather, it depends on $\Delta x$. As such, this is why you have $\epsilon \to 0$ instead of $\epsilon = 0$.

Comment: I wanted to say, if we take the limit as Δx goes to 0 for the equation (1) you wrote, then we have $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} ε = 0$. But now I see that ε actually depends on Δx so the limit is correct. But I still cant understand your answer. I know It cant be 0 because then Δy  = dy, but Im stuck witht the definition of $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ as Δx approaches 0, that is exactly f'(a).

Comment: @ToniIvanov Yes, you're right $\epsilon$ isn't a constant. Instead, it depends on $\Delta x$. As for my answer, I've updated it to include some more details. Note if $\Delta x = 0$, actually $\Delta y = 0$. In particular, $dy$, as in $\frac{dy}{dt}$, doesn't have any particular value but, instead, is notation for a differential. Thus, you don't have $\Delta y = dy$. Note, in general, for any $\Delta x \neq 0$, that $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ is *not* equal to $f'(a)$, although it can become arbitrarily close to it. This is why $\epsilon \neq 0$, but $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}\epsilon = 0$.